# Oauth2 Create User Forbidden

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-api-dotnet-client

Using OAuth2 from Google.apis.auth.OAuth2 and getting a 'Forbidden' message.  Can't find place to 'allow' in Developers/Apps consoles, beyond the turning on of APIs.  Have turned on Admin SDK, Google+ APIs.

Here is the response I receive:
Create users in a google apps domain!

> [lccFProcessGoogleAPI] ERROR: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>   Not Authorized to access this resource/api [403]
>   Errors [Message[Not Authorized to access this resource/api] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]]

I am using VS 2013, C#. Here is the code snip:

```
ServiceAccountCredential credential2 = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(lccSCSettings.lccSGoogleServiceAccountEmail)
    {
                               Scopes = new[] { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser }
                               //Scopes = new[] { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser, DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUserSecurity, DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroup, DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroupMember, DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryOrgunit }
                               //Scopes = new[] { PlusService.Scope.PlusMe }
                           }.FromCertificate(certificate2));
                        User newuserbody = new User();
    [...]
                    var service2 = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential2,
                ApplicationName = "lccGoogleAPI",
            });
           User results = service2.Users.Insert(newuserbody).Execute();
```

Comment: What language and programming environment is this?  The code causing the problem would also be helpful.  Please edit this information into your question.

Comment: Please don't try to put code in comments.  Delete those, then *edit the code into your question*.

Comment: All set.  Does that help?